# MySQL conditional date query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE TABLE test (
revisionId char primary key,
claimId char,
revisionDate datetime,
lossDate datetime
);

INSERT INTO test (id, claimId, revisionDate, lossDate)
VALUES
('asdjb990n','oo223',2020-01-01 10:30:00,2020-01-30 12:30:00)
('asdjb990n2','oo223',2020-01-02 10:30:00,2020-01-30 12:30:00)

('asdjkn897','ioas992', 2020-04-02 11:30:00,2020-04-01 10:30:00)
('asdjkn123','ioas992', 2020-04-03 11:30:00,2020-04-01 10:30:00)

('sdnjkn998','oo2231', 2020-02-02 12:31:00,2020-02-15 11:00:00)
```

This is an insurance problem. I have claim loss dates and policy revision dates. Most of the time there is a revision before the loss date. 99% of the time we want to include the revisionId that has the revisionDate closest to before the lossDate. In the case of claimId 'oo223' the closest revisionDate before the lossDate is with revisionId 'asdjb990n2'

The situation where this doesn't work is as follows:

Let's say we buy another insurance company. When we buy their company we also take on their claims. In that case we may have a lossDate before any revisionId exists (as in revision id = 'asdjkn897').

I need some way of saying :

> For every claimId if there is a revisionDate before the lossDate include the revisionId that comes closest to before the lossDate or else include the earliest revisionId after the lossDate if there are none before.

So in the case of claimId = 'ioas992' since revisionid = 'asdjkn897' has a revisionDate of 2020-04-02 I would want that revisionId given it is the earliest revision after the loss date (since there was no revision before the lossDate).

EDIT: Sorry I had the last line with the wrong loss date

All I want to return is the revisionId associated with the correct revisionDate for each claim id. So

claimID __revisionId

'oo223'    -    'asdjb990n2'

'ioas992'   -    'asdjkn897'

'oo2231'     -   'sdjkn998'

Comment: quote the dates. 2020-04-02 = 2014. What MYSQL version? One with window functions like MariaDB-10.2+ / MySQL-8.0+ would help

Comment: Please provide the desired result in a tabulated form

Comment: You have different loss dates for the same claim on different rows.  Hence, I don't understand the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the loss dates are consistent on all the rows for a claim, then you can use aggregation:

```
select t.claimid,
       coalesce(max(case when revisionDate < lossdate then revisionDate end),
                min(case when revisionDate > lossdate then revisionDate end)
                )
from test t
group by claimid;
```

Basically, this looks for the maximum revision date before the loss.  If there is none, it goes for the first after that date.

You can then join back to the table to get more information about the revision.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18f1148e5d553b79af4c66282d7c877e) is a db<>fiddle.